# Keep SSL keyfile open in Python

Tags: python, security, ssl, pem, passphrase

I'm using Python's [`ssl`](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html) library with an encrypted keyfile. However every time I [wrap a socket](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket), I'm prompted for the passphrase.

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

How can I give the passphrase just once, and have Python hold the decrypted key open for the lifetime of the process?

I'm very interested in the canonical openssl command line or C equivalent for this functionality also (assuming it assists in this situation).

I'd rather not resort to using `subprocess` and explicitly decoding/deleting the decrypted key. However if there is no alternative, a clean, secure suggestion guaranteeing the destruction and privacy of the decrypted key is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue3823) is fixed in [Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket), and [Python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts).